# Model does not support probabiliy estimates in libsvm

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I used libsvm in Matlab with the option `'-b 1'` in both training and prediction process. But it always returns `Model does not support probabiliy estimates`, so I don't get any probability or accuracy estimation. I tried in binary class SVM (not nu-svm!), it should have work with the `'-b 1'` but it's not. Does anyone know what's the reason for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the exact training command you used.

Comment: If you are doing regression, it would not have probability estimates. See [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README) and see if you can get their example running.

Comment: Keep in mind that probability estimates are not supported for one-class SVM. Quote from README: "-b probability_estimates: whether to predict probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0); for one-class SVM only 0 is supported"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let me show you the usage of **svm-predict**:

> Usage: svm-predict [options] test_file model_file output_file
>   options:
>
> -b probability_estimates: whether to predict probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0); for one-class SVM only 0 is supported
>
> -q : quiet mode (no outputs)

2. **svm-train:**

> Usage: svm-train [options] training_set_file [model_file] options:
>
> ```
> -s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
> ```
>
> 0 -- C-SVC      (multi-class classification)
>
> 1 -- nu-SVC     (multi-class classification)
>
> 2 -- one-class SVM
>
> 3 -- epsilon-SVR    (regression)    4 -- nu-SVR     (regression)
>
> -t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
>   0 -- linear: u'*v   1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
>
>   2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
>   3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
>
> 4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
>
> -d degree : set degree in kernel function (default 3)
>
> -g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
>
> -r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
>
> -c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)
>
> -n nu : set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
>
> -p epsilon : set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
>
> -m cachesize : set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
>
> -e epsilon : set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
>
> -h shrinking : whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
>
> **-b probability_estimates : whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)**
>
> -wi weight : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
>
> -v n: n-fold cross validation mode
>
> -q : quiet mode (no outputs)

We can see that the last fourth line is -b option. If we trained the model with '-b 1' option, we'll get a model that can output probability when you try to predict. Otherwise, if you only use '-b 1' option when you try to predict and not generate a model with '-b 1'. you will get the error : Model does not support probabiliy estimates

The main thing is that if you want to get probabiliy estimates, you should use '**-b 1**' in your **train** and **test** process, both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your questions needs more information to get a proper answer. but generally, the part that is giving error is here in the source code:

```
try 
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(argv[i]));
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(argv[i+2])));
            svm_model model = svm.svm_load_model(argv[i+1]);
            if(predict_probability == 1)
            {
                if(svm.svm_check_probability_model(model)==0)
                {
                    System.err.print("Model does not support probabiliy estimates\n");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(svm.svm_check_probability_model(model)!=0)
                {
                    System.out.print("Model supports probability estimates, but disabled in prediction.\n");
                }
            }
            predict(input,output,model,predict_probability);
            input.close();
            output.close();
        } 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            exit_with_help();
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
        {
            exit_with_help();
        }
    }
```

it mean it has does not find the probability model.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where is the svm_check_probability_model(model) function? I checked from a bunch of .c and .cpp files included but failed to find it