# SVM Model does not support probability estimation?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am doing some classification task with Support Vector Machines (SVM). 
I am using libSVM (with Matlab support) to predict probability estimates matrix. However, the libSVM displays message that;
Model does not support probabiliy estimates
Below is my sample code;
(train_label contains labels for training data and test_label contains label for test data)

```
    model = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, '-t 2 -g .01 -c 0.7 -b 1);
    [y,accuracy,prob_estimates]=svmpredict(test_label,test_data,model,'-b 1');
```

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with the way I am doing it? Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the Matlab implementation, but usually you have to set this [option](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/):

> -b probability_estimates: whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I have already set the option '-b 1' for training and prediction.

Comment: @user35919 Sorry, overlooked that. Have you tried different SVM types using the `-t` option? (I'm just guessing, not sure whether this will help).

Comment: Yes, I did try with '-t 1' and '-t 2'. Makes no difference.

Comment: @user35919 Apologies again, `-t` specifies the kernel type, I wanted to suggest to try a different SVM type, which is specified through `-s` [0... 4]. This is my last guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using libsvm in the same way without any problem.

In your code only a ' is missing in the following line

```
model = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, '-t 2 -g .01 -c 0.7 -b 1);
```

It should be

```
model = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, '-t 2 -g .01 -c 0.7 -b 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, model hasn't got `ProbA` and `ProbB` in it. 
Before it was like this and giving error:

```
linear_model = svmtrain(trainClass, trainData, ['-t 0', cmd]);
```

Then I changed it to this, error dissappared:) - removed cmd and put exact values

```
linear_model = svmtrain(trainClass, trainData, ['-t 0 -c 1 -g 0.125 -b 1']);
```

if still gives error try to change `c` and `g` parameters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your model does not support probabiliy estimates.

You should use '-b 1' option both at training and testing process.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43509667/7893127

Answer (score 0):

You may just train the model with default parameter.
Try to use '-b 1' when you are training and testing programe.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

`C:\setup\python36\Lib\site-packages\svm.py` default value of `self.probability` is `0`. You can set it `1`.

[image]